# Get last X rows order by asc

Tags: mysql, order-by

I want to select last X rows from a table, so what I did was:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 120
```

and it worked, but I want it to be ordered ascending, so I tried with:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 120 ORDER BY id ASC
```

expecting that it would reorder selected rows, but it didn't work.

So how can I achieve it?

Comment: You were not downvoted, the question was. Someone (from the 15 that viewed it) thought it could be improved or that it wasn't good enough.

Comment: I added the mysql tag by the way, based on the `LIMIT` clause. If you use another DBMS (eg SQLite), please edit accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the question I mean, and right, I forgot to mention that it was about MySQl, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even this will work:

```
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... ) ORDER BY ...;
```

That is, no need in the syntax for the outer `SELECT`.

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to do something like this.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 120) AS t
ORDER BY t.id ASC ;
```

Another alternative would be to load the results into a temp table, then query that for the desired order.

Comment: should be `order by t.id asc` - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5912827/1387418

Comment: @Kin `order by id asc` works fine, too. There is only one table named `t` at that level.

Comment: So I must make a double SELECT right? I was thinking about that or UNION... isn't there any more direct and/or efficient way to do it? thanks

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yeh it works. I mentioned it just as a good practice :-)